# combobox is not showing added items

Tags: excel, vba

```
.cmbcom11.AddItem "cotton"
.cmbcom11.AddItem "elastane"
.cmbcom11.AddItem "polyester elastane"
.cmbcom11.AddItem "nylon elastane"
.cmbcom11.AddItem "seashell"
```

This is the method I used to add the a list for one of the combo boxes in the following interface

[image]

cmbcom11 is composition 1 (first row) and 12 will be the next one and 13 will the one after

I just showed a small part of the code which I will be repeating for all `cmbcom`

I know I got the name right when typing because there is no compile error or runtime error

Then why isnt my list showing up in the combo box?

Comment: Where is the code? Is it in Userform_Inititalize event?

Comment: i believe its in an area called module

Comment: Right click the Userform, click "View Code" and make a sub `Sub Userform_Initialize()` then paste your code there. The code will in that sub will run automatically when the userform is loaded

Comment: Assuming the name of the control is `cmbcom11`, the code will be something like `cmbcom11.AddItem "cotton"`, without the "." before cmbcom11

Comment: @RaymondWu can i share a link from where i got the code inspiration from? i did exactly what that dude did ...only difference is that his interface is not that complicated and it does not have tabs .....https://youtu.be/P53T6oxgUVA?t=1187         go to 19:47 of the video

Comment: @Mario. I'm not sure how is the video relevant to your question?

Comment: he didhnt use Sub Userform_Initialize() but it worked.....i did the same but it didnt :(

Comment: @Marion He called sub `Reset` in sub `Userform_Initialize` so yes it worked for him. did you do the same?

Comment: i did use sub reset but i dont see any sub userform_initialize ?...the top part of my code has his part ...im sorry if im bombarding with questions ...im reallys stuck with this..is there anyway i can send you my code :/

Comment: @Marion See 32:11 of the video... did you even follow the entire video first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand where your code lives and how it is called.

In the video, a subroutine `Reset` is defined that fills up the controls of the form: It empties the textboxes and sets the options of the combobox. This sub is stored in a regular module. It could also be in the code of the form itself (except that you would write `Me.txtId.Value` instead of `frmForm.txtId.Value`).

However, this routine `reset` needs to be called (and that is the point you are missing). When do you want to execute this routine? Exactly in the moment the form is shown - or more precise when someone tells the form "please show yourself", but before the user sees the form.

A form (and all controls on the form) has events that are called automatically at a certain *event*. In VBA, those event routine names contain two parts, the first part is the name of the control, the second part is the name of the event. These names are fix, if you change them, the VBA runtime will not find them and nothing will happen.

Now those event routines need to be in the (object) code. For a form, go to the form editor and press F7: This is the code of the form. Press the left drop down on the top of the editor: It contains all controls of the form, including the form itself. Select "Userform". Now you see all events of the form that you can handle in the right drop down. Select "Initialize". You will notice that an empty routine `Userform_Initialize` is added to the code. Add the statement `Reset` (or `Call Reset`) to this routine. This *event* routine is called when the form is *initialized*, do whatever you need before the form gets visible.

In the video, the author has some more event routines that reacts on the click of the buttons: Those routines need to be also in the code of the form. It's of no use to put them in a separate module, the VBA event handler cannot find them.

Last remark: To show the form, the author placed a big shape on the sheet. Clicking this shape calls also an event routine, however, you are free to name the routine whatever you want, and this routine needs to be in a module. In the video, it is named `show_form`. Just be sure that you don't rename it after you assigned it to the shape.